# Create/write/read a text file external to the Jar archive

Tags: java, file-io, io

To save the state of a Java programmed video game in a text file (it is an exercise for a school project, I can't use serialization), I have to create a text file and write in it with `PrintWriter`, then read it with `Scanner`.

Until today I was creating the file in this directory :

```
PrintWriter vPW;
try {vPW = new PrintWriter("./saves/" + vFileName + ".txt");}
catch (final IOException pExp) {
        player.getGUI().println("Failed to create the file.");
        return;
}
```

Now that I had created a Jar archive of my project, I realize I can't create files in the archive while running the program.

I tried to create a file with these directories, but none of them worked :

```
vPW = new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/gamesaves/" + vNomFichier + ".txt")
```

or

```
vPW = new PrintWriter("C:/saves/" + vFileName + ".txt")
```

How could I create, edit and read a text file somewhere on the system?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) When in doubt, print out!  A well placed call to `System.out.println(thing.toString())` or `File.exists()` or `File.getAbsolutePath()` can save a lot of head-aches.  Alternately, use the debugger of your IDE to step through the code. 3) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Comment: make sure the directory where you are tying to create the file [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()),  [is a directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) and [can be written to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite()). If it is not existing you can create it using [mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to create the folder first:

```
final File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "gamesaves");
if(!folder.exists() && !folder.mkDirs()) {
   //failed to create the folder, probably exit
   throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create save directory.");
}
final File myFile = new File(folder, vNomFichier + ".txt");
final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myFile);
```

You can also check whether your application is allowed to write where you are asking it to with `folder.canWrite()`. If that returns `false` then the application does not have permission to write to that folder (or it does not exist).

Comment: Seems `//failed to create the folder
}..` should be `//failed to create the folder
} else {..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson added an exception to make clear that the thing should probably exit at that point.